# How to limit resource usage for a process in rust

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a process

```
use std::process::Command;
let output = Command::new("my_program")
                     .arg("file.txt")
                     .output()
                     .expect("failed to execute process");
```

How can I limit resources to this command like max RAM usage to 1024MB and cpus=2

I tried using ulimit with the command but it's not working

```
ulimit -m 125000; my_program file.txt
use std::process::Command;
let output = Command::new("ulimit")
                     .arg("-m")
                     .arg("125000")
                     .arg(";")
                     .arg("my_program")
                     .arg("file.txt")
                     .output()
                     .expect("failed to execute process");
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using ulimit with the command but it's not working

That is because `ulimit` is a shell builtin, not a command.

The way to **s**et **r**esource limits on a subprocess is to use [`setrlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) as part of [`CommandExt::pre_exec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.pre_exec).

As far as I know the stdlib does not have a `setrlimit` bridge, but you should be able to find one in the libc or nix crates.